# How to get Python variables to Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to get the random values generated in 'randgen' displayed as text in the button (right now the button displays string). How can I get rand_val into the .kv file?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random

root = Builder.load_string('''
<Demo>:
    cols: 1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'rand_val_here'
            size_hint: .2, .2
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'center_y': .1}

''')
class Demo(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.randgen, 0.01)
        return Demo()

    def randgen(dt, self):
        rand_val = random.randint(0, 10)
        print(rand_val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments and names of some functions are not correct, I think they are caused because you have tried to copy and remove the secondary part but remember that the order is interesting in python.

If you want to assign a property to a Widget you must first obtain it and for them an `id` must be placed, this id will be the name of the variable that will be created and assigned, we can access it through `ids` as I show below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random

root = Builder.load_string('''
<Demo>:
    cols: 1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            id: btn
            size_hint: .2, .2
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'center_y': .1}

''')
class Demo(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        BoxLayout.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.randgen, 0.01)

    def randgen(self, dt):
        rand_val = random.randint(0, 10)
        self.ids.btn.text = str(rand_val)
        print(rand_val)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Demo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: self.ids.btn.text = str(rand_val) - that's what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods of solving this. The method 1 is using ObjectProperty, and the method 2 is using StringProperty.

## Method 1 - Using ObjectProperty

In this example, an ObjectProperty is used to hook up to the button because an id is a weakref to the widget. Using ObjectProperty creates a direct reference, provides faster access and is more explicit.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random

root = Builder.load_string('''
<Demo>:
    btn: btn
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        id: btn
        text: 'rand_val_here'
        size_hint: .2, .2
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'center_y': .1}

''')


class Demo(BoxLayout):
    btn = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Demo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.randgen, 0.01)

    def randgen(self, dt):
        self.btn.text = str(random.randint(0, 10))


class MainApp(App):
    title = "Updating Button's Text - Using ObjectProperty"

    def build(self):
        return Demo()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

### Output

[image: Figure 1: Method 1 - Using ObjectProperty]

## Method 2 - Using StringProperty

Without changing much of your original app, the solution is as follow:

1. Since your root widget class, Demo is a BoxLayout, therefore the attribute ***cols: 1*** which is only applicable to GridLayout is not required in the kv file
2. Declare ***rand_val*** of type ***StringProperty***
3. Populate the button's text using ***app.rand_val***

**Note:**
Your app has nested BoxLayout.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random

root = Builder.load_string('''
<Demo>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: app.rand_val
            size_hint: .2, .2
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'center_y': .1}

''')


class Demo(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    rand_val = StringProperty("")

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.randgen, 0.01)
        return Demo()

    def randgen(self, dt):
        self.rand_val = str(random.randint(0, 10))
        print(self.rand_val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

### Output

[image: Figure 2: Method 2 - Using StringProperty]

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why was it voted down though. Again, thanks @ikolim!